# How to paginate a list of objects which contains a list of object

Tags: java, struts, displaytag

I have an Object called Person which has the following attributes:

```
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private List<UserDetails> userList;
```

Now I have to display a list of persons and it requires to have pagination.
I am thinking to use a display tag. However I'm not able to find out how to display a list inside a list of object using display tag as I am a newbie to display tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<display:table name="test" id="person">
   <c:set var="userListVar" value="test.item[${parent_rowNum -1}].userList" />

  <display:column title="Related address">

    <display:table name="${userListVar}" id="child${parent_rowNum}" class="simple sublist">
        <display:column property="name" />

    </display:table>
  </display:column>
</display:table>
```

for your refference

http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-nestedtables.jsp

Comment: the special character which is used here $..it is displaytag specific?

Comment: this is ${} EL expression in JSP